# Using Vim, what is the best way to implement PHP code folding that only folds functions blocks?

Tags: php, vim, folding

I'm currently using Vim to edit PHP files and would like to implement code folding for functions only. I've tried setting the `foldmethod=expr` and using a regex with `foldexpr` in my .vimrc file. The problem is i don't fully understand how `foldexpr` is using the regex to apply folding to the source code and i can't seem to get it right.

Basically i want all PHP functions (inside classes too) to be folded and that's it. The nearest i've got is:

```
set foldexpr=getline(v:lnum-1)=~'function'?'>1':'='
```

but it's not right and i want to see if i can be a little more intelligent with the curly braces.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIRC folding do not work with regexes because it will slow vim down. You might get what you want by using foldmethod=indent and set foldnestmax to limit the number of nested folds created.

Answer (score 12):

I achieved what i needed by using the built-in PHP plugin, activated by putting this in my .vimrc file and not using any other folding settings.

```
let php_folding = 1        "Set PHP folding of classes and functions.
let php_htmlInStrings = 1  "Syntax highlight HTML code inside PHP strings.
let php_sql_query = 1      "Syntax highlight SQL code inside PHP strings.
let php_noShortTags = 1    "Disable PHP short tags.
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [phpfolding plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1623).

This is much better than the built-in `php_folding` syntax stuff because it understands phpdoc/doxygen docblocks, folds the code so you can still see the function name (but hides the documentation which precedes it).

Example:

[image: screenshot]

It is a bit weird, you need to run `:EnablePHPFolds` to update stuff, and I get an odd message when I start up Vim (but that might be because I've installed it with Vundle), but it's a thing of beauty!

(Also referenced at https://stackoverflow.com/a/11859632/623519)

Comment: I've moved on to this other folding plugin https://github.com/swekaj/php-foldexpr.vim